# What R data package (or data from other source) with many variables to econometric model?

Tags: r, economics

I would like to ask if you know any R packages with data to do linear econometric model (least squares method). I must have 5-7 variables (some of them can occur insignificant later). I should check heteroscedascity, autocorelation, catalysis etc. Mayby you can recommend me data from other source f.e.  other math program data package?

Comment: We have a special site devoted to statistics and data science, http://crossvalidated.com ; it may be more fruitful to ask such questions there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cool package on CRAN: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HistData/index.html

> The `HistData' package provides a
>   collection of small data sets that are
>   interesting and important in the
>   history of statistics and data
>   visualization. The goal of the package
>   is to make these available, both for
>   instructional use and for historical
>   research. Some of these present
>   interesting challenges for graphics or
>   analysis in R.

[Insert apologies for shameless self-promotion here] You could also use the `WDI` package to download data from the World Bank's World Development indicators. For instance, here's a least squares regression of GDP per capita on trade as a % of GDP and the density of a country's road network.

```
library(WDI)
ind <- c('NY.GDP.PCAP.CD', 'NE.TRD.GNFS.ZS', 'IS.ROD.DNST.K2')
dat <- WDI(country='all', start=2002, end=2002, indicator=ind)
names(dat) <- c('country', 'iso2c', 'year', 'gdp.per.cap', 'trade.to.gdp', 'roads')
mod <- lm(gdp.per.cap ~ trade.to.gdp + roads, dat)
summary(mod)
```

You can search for new data with keywords:

```
WDIsearch('forest')
```

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/WDI/index.html

Answer (score 1):

May be you should find the **Ecdat** Package useful....this package contains a lot of data from econometrics textbooks and articles.

```
install.packages("Ecdat")
```